# Evaluating $ L = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$, when $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ isn't even defined for $x\in(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

In Mary Hart's *Guide to Analysis*, one of the exercises page 157 is to evaluate the following limit:

$$ L = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$$

As this function has square roots in the denominator, I had tried to rationalise it which yielded the following:

$$ L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{2}$$

By splitting up the 2 terms in the numerator, I had tried to evaluate them separately.

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{2} + \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{2}$$

Clearly, $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

But I don't know how it is possible to evaluate

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{2}$$ as the function $ \sqrt{x^2 -1}$ isn't even defined for any $ x \in (-1,1)$ and therefore I can't see how it can have a limit as $x \to 0$. My understanding is that in order for a limit to exist as $x\to 0$, a function must first be defined for any $ x \in (-R,R) \setminus \{0\}$ where $R$ is any positive number. Hence the fact that this function isn't defined in $(-1,1)$ should prevent this limit from existing at all.

Note:
The answer in the book is that $ L =1$ which would imply that $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're allowed/directed to go into complex numbers, the question makes no sense since the function simply does not exist, as a real function, in any open neighborhood of zero...I'd say the above  could be a good solution.

Comment: Might be an error or something. If complex values are allowed, the limit should be $\frac{1+i}{2}$.

Comment: @Tavish Actually, as a complex limit, it doesn't exists.

Comment: @jjagmath How? Because $\sqrt {-1} = \pm i$?

Comment: @Tavish It depends wheter you mean it as a limit of a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. If the former, then there is an argument for doing it your way. If the latter, then it's what jjagmath says *if* you choose the principal square root which is discontinuous ar $\Re z<0$.

Comment: @Tavish The standard way of choosing a principal square root has a branch cut in $(-\infty,0)$. Because of this, $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is discontinuous at $0$ (while $\sqrt{z^2+1}$ is continuous at $0$)

Comment: @Gae.S. Interesting.

Comment: @jjagmath What is a ‘branch cut’?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of this exercise  (and the answer)?